# Freestyle SVG Export rendering lines that aren't there

Tags: freestyle, svg

I've got a mesh (originally curve but added depth and converted), which I'm trying to export as an SVG, however, Blender is rendering lines in the SVG that aren't there in the mesh. Does anyone know how to get rid of these?

[image: the render of the object without freestyle]

[image: render of the object with freestyle]

Thanks,
Erin

Comment: I'm guessing the strands are so thin, that Freestyle only renders a single line, and that the SVG exporter then makes it a closed curve, which would explain the extra lines: it simply adds a line from the last point to the first point to close it. I do not know for certain that this is the problem, which is why I'm commenting instead of posting an answer. You could try to make the Freestyle lines as thin as possible and/or making the strands thicker, thus making the outline of each individual strand a closed curve.